# How can I change the size of a plot in Sweave?

Tags: r, latex, size, sweave

I am trying to change the size of the plot for the PDF because it takes up almost half a page. However, I can't manage to do it.

This is my code for the two plots which should go next to each other and be reduced in height:

```
well<-paste(LETTERS[1:8])

#Rhodamine B data set
rhodcolumn1<-c(9931,10252,9170,7763,5491,3503,2313,1046)
rhodcolumn2<-c(9957,10205,9658,7568,5368,3886,2938,1070)
rhod_data<-data.frame(rhodcolumn1,rhodcolumn2)
row.names(rhod_data)<-well

#Rhodamine B plot
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(rhod_data$rhodcolumn1,xaxt="n",main="Rhodamine dilution",col=2,pch=1,xlab="Well",ylab="Concentration")
axis(1, at=1:8, labels=LETTERS[1:8])
points(rhod_data$rhodcolumn2,pch=1,col=3)
legend('topright', names(rhod_data)[1:2],pch=1, col=c('red', 'green'), bty='n', cex=.75)
lines(rhod_data$rhodcolumn1,pch=1,col=2)
lines(rhod_data$rhodcolumn2,pch=1,col=3)

#Crystal violet data set
cryscolumn1<-c(0.181,0.108,0.09,0.087,0.097,0.092,0.086,0.092)
cryscolumn2<-c(0.181,0.104,0.09,0.087,0.089,0.085,0.098,0.085)
crys_data<-data.frame(cryscolumn1,cryscolumn2)
row.names(crys_data)<-well

#Crystal violet plot
plot(crys_data$cryscolumn1,xaxt="n",main="Crystaline violet dilution",col=2,pch=1,xlab="Well",ylab="Concentration")
axis(1, at=1:8, labels=LETTERS[1:8])
points(crys_data$cryscolumn2,pch=1,col=3)
legend('topright', names(crys_data)[1:2],pch=1, col=c('red', 'green'), bty='n', cex=.75)
lines(crys_data$cryscolumn1,pch=1,col=2)
lines(crys_data$cryscolumn2,pch=1,col=3)
```

I am sorry, I couln't figure out how to insert the code here with colours.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Each chunk can have their own specifications. One of them is fig.width:

````
```{r chunk1, fig.width = 0.5\textwidth}
plot
```
````

If you want the same size of all plots you can define it at the top. I use knitr and it looks like this:

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, fig.width = 0.5\textwidth)
```
````